# How to list out all the files in the public directory in a Play Framework 2.X Scala application?

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

Here is my controller

```
class Proguard extends Controller {

  val proguardFolder = "/public/proguards/"
  val proguardFolderFix = "/public/proguards"
  val proguardSuffix = "proguard-"
  val proguardExtension = ".pro"
  val title = "# Created by https://www.proguard.io/api/%s\n\n%s"

  def proguard(libraryName: String) = Action {
    val libraries = libraryName.split(',')

    val availableLibs = listInDir(proguardFolderFix)
    val result = availableLibs.filter(libraries.contains).map(readFile).mkString
    Ok(title.format(libraryName, result))
  }


  def list() = Action {
    Ok(Json.toJson(listInDir(proguardFolder)))
  }

  private def listInDir(filePath: String): List[String] = {
    getListOfFiles(Play.getFile(filePath)).map(_.getName.replace(proguardExtension, "").replace(proguardSuffix, ""))
  }

  def getListOfFiles(dir: File): List[File] = {
    dir.listFiles.toList
  }

  def readFile(string: String): String = {
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(Play.getFile(s"$proguardFolder$proguardSuffix$string$proguardExtension"))
    val lines = try source.mkString finally source.close()
    lines
  }

}
```

It worked totally okay in debug mode, but in production at Heroku `dir.listFiles.` is giving me NPE

I've tried different ways, but looks like only solution is move my files to s3 or database.

Comment: Can you check if the dir exists on Heroku by running `heroku run bash` and using `ls` to look for it?

Comment: How are you populating your public directory? Anything you upload to a `start`ed app isn't going to be uploaded there. Only resources that exist before you `start` an app would be listed.

Comment: @codefinger Looks like yes, folder and files exist on heroku http://joxi.ru/DmBE0XGcxZqorP

Comment: @0fnt all files are inside my public folder before build and are uploaded with it.